# How to install source sans pro in ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, fonts

I like this font because its free but i am unable to install it in my ubuntu 14.04. I did a lot of research on this but all results give me source code pro. Which is also developed by adobe but a different font that source sans pro. This is the link for this font https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-sans-pro

Comment: Download, extract, double click.

Comment: Please add the linkt to the duplicate! I did not find it, but I found this thread.